# Moxa RealTTY module compilation error on Linux kernel 3.16

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, linux-device-driver

I used MOXA devices on Debian 7.0 with kernel 3.2. I was able to successfully compiled Moxa RealTTY driver for this kernel, but after I upgraded to Debian 8.0 with kernel 3.16 I can't compile it. 
I asked MOXA for newest driver, but so far no answer. Latest driver was downloaded from this link http://mtsc.moxa.com:8888/Software/DN/NPort/Driver/RealTTY/ , but this link does not work anymore.

When I run ./mxinst it crash on this error:
        ===============================================================================
    Copyright (C) 2002-2014  Moxa Inc.
    All Rights Reserved.

```
MOXA NPort Server Real TTY Driver V1.18.33 Installation.
System Information: Kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64; Machine x86_64.
===============================================================================


Tar files, please wait ... OK!  
Building driver...

If you want to use secure communication with target,
you might choose [y] to enable the SSL function.
Note: This function support RealCOM with secure mode only.
Do you want to enable secure function? [y/N].
n
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/opt/moxa.git/npreal2 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
  CC [M]  /opt/moxa.git/npreal2/npreal2.o
/opt/moxa.git/npreal2/npreal2.c: In function ‘npreal_wait_command_completed’:
/opt/moxa.git/npreal2/npreal2.c:4744:13: error: implicit declaration of function ‘interruptible_sleep_on_timeout’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
             interruptible_sleep_on_timeout(&nd->cmd_rsp_wait,timeout);
             ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/scripts/Makefile.build:268: recipe for target '/opt/moxa.git/npreal2/npreal2.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/opt/moxa.git/npreal2/npreal2.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/Makefile:1350: recipe for target '_module_/opt/moxa.git/npreal2' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/opt/moxa.git/npreal2] Error 2
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2 
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
Makefile:67: recipe for target 'module' failed
make: *** [module] Error 2
Check Driver...
FAILED !!!

Install Not Completed !
```

I have uploaded latest driver to GitHub (https://github.com/rchovan/npreal2). Can someone help me to fix this module to compile it on Linux kernel 3.16 and newest ?

Thank You

Comment: what have you done to resolve the problem with the missing function: 'interruptible_sleep_on_timeout()'

Comment: Hi, I didn't solved it yet. I'm not familiar with C language and Linux kernel module development. My experiences end with source compilation.

Comment: Hello. A new version of the driver is available. Please contact support@moxa.com and ask for the new linux driver (beta driver, but so far has worked on almost every linux system). I will then supply you with the required driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `interruptible_sleep_on_timeout` has been removed in kernel version 3.15.

The workaround for the missing function can be found in many patches, for example this [lm-sensors patch](http://lists.lm-sensors.org/pipermail/lm-sensors/2005-February/010415.html):

```
-           timeout = interruptible_sleep_on_timeout(&w1_control_wait, timeout);
+           prepare_to_wait(&w1_control_wait, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
+           timeout = schedule_timeout(timeout);
+           finish_wait(&w1_control_wait, &wait);
```

I patched moxa driver according to this solution and made a pull request on your github repo. Please test it.

Comment: Hi, patch is OK. Module was compiled and is fully functional. Thank You